# record game score on a tap me game

Tags: ios

IOS Game
I am creating a game were there is a button and there aim of the game is see how much taps you can get before the time runs out

But i have a problem i need to recored the high score, how can i do that.

.h code

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface errrViewController : UIViewController{

IBOutlet UILabel *label;
IBOutlet UILabel *timerLabel;

NSInteger count;
NSInteger seconds;

NSTimer *timer; //ADD THIS!!
}

- (IBAction) buttonPressed;
- (void)setupGame;
- (void)subtractTime;



@end
```

m. code

```
#import "errrViewController.h"

@interface errrViewController ()

@end

@implementation errrViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self setupGame];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



//Implementing our method
- (IBAction)buttonPressed{
    count++;

    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score\n%i",count];
}

- (void)setupGame{
    seconds = 30;
    count = 0;

    timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time: %i",seconds];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score\n%i",count];

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(subtractTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

- (void)subtractTime{
    seconds--;
    timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time: %i",seconds];

    if(seconds == 0){
        [timer invalidate];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Time is up!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You scored %i points",count] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Play Again" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    [self setupGame];
}

@end

#import "errrViewController.h"

@interface errrViewController ()

@end

@implementation errrViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self setupGame];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



//Implementing our method
- (IBAction)buttonPressed{
    count++;

    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score\n%i",count];
}

- (void)setupGame{
    seconds = 30;
    count = 0;

    timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time: %i",seconds];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score\n%i",count];

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(subtractTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

- (void)subtractTime{
    seconds--;
    timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time: %i",seconds];

    if(seconds == 0){
        [timer invalidate];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Time is up!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You scored %i points",count] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Play Again" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    [self setupGame];
}




@end
```

Please explain how to do this in steps

Please provide any links if possible that can help me

Comment: You need to better describe what you have tried, and what the problem with it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by saving the highscore to a plist file, in the form of a NSDictionary. For example:

```
int highscore; //your highscore variable, which I believe you can calculate yourself
```

Then you can have a save function like:

```
-(void) saveHighscore{
    NSDictionary* highscoreDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", highscore], @"Highscore",nil];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    //get the path for the documents directory
    NSString* filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Highscore.plist"];
    //Check if file exists
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:filePath]){
        //delete it if it does, because we're going to replace it anyway
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager]removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
    }
    [highscoreDict writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; // write to file
}
```

And you can have a load highscore function like:

```
-(int) loadHighscore{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Highscore.plist"];
    //Check if file exists
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:filePath]){
        NSDictionary* highscoreDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        //Retrieve the value of highscore from your file
        return [[highscoreDict valueForKey: @"Highscore"]intValue];
    }
    //Otherwise return 0 as the highscore
    return 0;
}
```

And add `[self loadHighscore];` in your `viewDidLoad` function.

Hope this helps.